# JobScheduler Not Working

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I have the following codes in my project but when i run it on my android emulator, it does not print any logs as it is supposed to do every 15 minutes.

```
public class JobSchedulerService extends JobService {

JobParameters params;
DoItTask doIt;

@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
    this.params = params;
    Log.d("TestService", "Work to be called from here");
    doIt = new DoItTask();
    doIt.execute();
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
    Log.d("TestService", "System calling to stop the job here");
    if (doIt != null)
        doIt.cancel(true);
    return false;
}

private class DoItTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        Log.d("DoItTask", "Clean up the task here and call jobFinished...");
        jobFinished(params, false);
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.d("DoItTask", "Working here...");
        return null;
    }
}

}
```

and I call this in my mainactivity java

```
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), JobSchedulerService.class);
    JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(1, componentName).setPeriodic(900002).build();
```

I also have this in my mainfest under the application tag

```
<service android:name=".JobSchedulerService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
```

Comment: Where is your call [to `schedule()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html#schedule(android.app.job.JobInfo))?

Comment: *am I supped to add that after.build()?* - read the docs man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `JobScheduler`, you need to:

- Create a `JobInfo`, as you are doing
- Get an instance of `JobScheduler` via `getSystemService()`
- Call `schedule()` on the `JobScheduler`, passing it the `JobInfo`